# Apollo codegen duplicating nested fragment imports

Tags: graphql, apollo, apollo-client, graphql-codegen, graphql-tag

I'm using reusable fragments in `.gql` files but the resulting query will declare the fragments multiple times when using codegen. A simplified example:

```
# ImagesInfos.gql
fragment ImageInfos {
  url
  alt
}
```

```
#Post.gql
#import './ImageInfos.gql'

fragment Post {
  title
  image {
    ... ImageInfos
  }
  user {
    ... UserInfos
  }

}
```

```
#User.gql
#import './ImageInfos.gql'

fragment User {
  name
  image {
    ... ImageInfos
  }
}
```

But this will result in multiple occurence of the declaration of ImageInfos fragment. How can I avoid this?